# Is it possible to Upsert using Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am using Stream Analytics to insert data into table storage. This works when all I want to do is add new rows. However, I now want to insert or update existing rows. Is this possible with Stream Analytics/Table storage?

Answer (score 3):

The current implementation of Stream Analytics output to Azure Table uses [InsertOrReplace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablebatchoperation.insertorreplace(v=azure.100).aspx) API. So as long as your new data is cumulative (not just the deltas) it should simply work. 
On the other hand,  if you would like only upsert (insert or update), you could consider DocumentDB [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output).

If you like something more customized, You could also consider a trigger in your SQL table output.

cheers
Chetan

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. Stream Analytics isn't an ETL tool.

However, you might be able to pass the output to a downstream SQLDB table. Then have a second stream job and query that joins the first to the table using left/right and inner joins. Just an idea, not tested, and not recommended.

OR

Maybe output the streamed data to a SQL DB landing table or Data Lake Store. Then perform a merge there before producing the output dataset. This would be a more natural approach.